# how to drawline with button event?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

MY program here is basically a JPanel with three buttons
I want to use one of the buttons to drawLine on the JPanel.
I have two classes one that extends JPanel (Panel.class)
and the other that extends the JFrame (frame.class)

The button is in the frame.class which calls a method in panel.class called drawer();
to which the button event passes xy co-ordinates and then drawer passes those co-ordinates to four int var in panel.class and invoke repaint(); but no line in drawn.

Panel.class code :

```
package my.jpanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Panel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
//draws using the initial (x1, y1) co-ordiantes of the previous i in the array 
    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
ArrayList linex1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList linex2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList liney1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList liney2 = new ArrayList();
public int fx1, fy1, fx2, fy2;

public void drawer(int fx1i, int fy1i, int fx2i, int fy2i){

fx1 = fx1i;
fy1 = fy1i;
fx2 = fx2i;
fy2 = fy2i;
repaint();
}

public Panel() {
    addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e){

            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();  

            int z = linex1.size();
            System.out.println("z: "+z);

            if (z!=0){
            linex1.add(linex2.get(z-1));
            liney1.add(liney2.get(z-1));}

            else{
                linex1.add(x1);
                liney1.add(y1);
                System.out.println("x1:"+x1);}

        }
        public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e){
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();

            linex2.add(x2);
            liney2.add(y2);

            System.out.println("x1:"+x1+" x2:"+x2+" y1: "+y1+" y2: "+y2);

            double slope = ((((double)y2)-((double)y1))/(((double)x2)-((double)x1)));

            System.out.println("Slope of line: "+slope);

            repaint();

        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener ( new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();

            repaint();

        }
    });


}
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(250, 150);
}
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent(g);
//  g.drawOval(Math.min(x1,  x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1-x2), Math.abs(y1-y2));
    g.drawLine(fx1, fy1, fx2, fy2);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    int lx1 = linex1.size();
    int lx2 = linex2.size();
    int ly1 = liney1.size();
    int ly2 = liney2.size();
    System.out.println("lx1: "+lx1);
    System.out.println("lx2: "+lx2);
    System.out.println("ly1: "+ly1);
    System.out.println("ly2: "+ly2);
    System.out.println("-------------");

    if ((lx1 != 0 && lx2 != 0 && ly1 != 0 && ly2 != 0) && (lx1 != 1 && ly1 != 1 && !(lx2 < (lx1)) && !(ly2 < (ly1)))){ 
    for (int i=0; i<lx1; ++i){
        int x1x = ((int) (linex1.get(i)));
        int x2x = ((int) (linex2.get(i)));
        int y1y = ((int) (liney1.get(i)));
        int y2y = ((int) (liney2.get(i)));
        g.drawLine(x1x,y1y,x2x, y2y);}

    if ((lx1 != 0 && lx2 != 0 && ly1 != 0 && ly2 != 0) && (lx1 != 1 && ly1 != 1 && lx2<lx1 && ly2<ly1)){ 
    for (int x1=0, x2=0; x1<linex1.size() &&  x2<linex2.size()-1; ++x1, ++x2){
        int x1x = ((int) (linex1.get(x1)));
        int x2x = ((int) (linex2.get(x2)));
        int y1y = ((int) (liney1.get(y1)));
        int y2y = ((int) (liney2.get(y2)));
        g.drawLine(x1x,y1y,x2x, y2y);}
        }
    }
}

public void Panelint() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 204, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration
```

}

frame.class code is below:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package my.jpanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

   // }
public class frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ArrayList<Integer> drawnpattern = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> filepattern = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public frame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    panel1 = new my.jpanel.Panel();
    btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jta = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtondraw = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 204, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
    panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
    panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    btn.setText("Print Co-ordinate and Save File");
    btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jta.setColumns(20);
    jta.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jta);

    jButton1.setText("Match patterns");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButtondraw.setText("Draw Both line");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btn)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 24, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButtondraw)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(107, 107, 107))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 43, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btn)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButtondraw))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    String axis = null;
for (int i=0; i<(panel1.linex1.size()); ++i ){
axis = ("Line "+i+": "+" x1: "+panel1.linex1.get(i)+" y1: "+panel1.liney1.get(i)+" x2: "+panel1.linex2.get(i)+" y2: "+panel1.liney2.get(i)+".");
jta.append(axis);
    jta.append("\n");
    }
               try {
        File file = new File("I:/Programming/linedata.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true); // append=true so that we don't overwrite the whole file
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); // buffer writing
        for (int i=0; i<(panel1.linex1.size()); ++i ){
                    bw.write("x1:"+panel1.linex1.get(i));
                    bw.write("y1:"+panel1.liney1.get(i));
                    bw.write("x2:"+panel1.linex2.get(i));
                    bw.write("y2:"+panel1.liney2.get(i));
                    }
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}                                   

private void jButtondrawActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    //for (int i=0; i<((filepattern.size())/4); i++){
    filepattern.add(26);
    filepattern.add(50);
    filepattern.add(36);
    filepattern.add(130);
    filepattern.add(36);
    filepattern.add(130);
    filepattern.add(64);
    filepattern.add(97);
    filepattern.add(64);
    filepattern.add(97);
    filepattern.add(81);
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(81);    
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(100);
    filepattern.add(96);
    filepattern.add(100);
    filepattern.add(96);
    filepattern.add(122);
    filepattern.add(128);
    filepattern.add(122);
    filepattern.add(128);
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(57);
        int fx1 = filepattern.get(0);
        int fy1 = filepattern.get(1);
        int fx2 = filepattern.get(2);
        int fy2 = filepattern.get(3);
        panel1.drawer(fx1, fy1, fx2, fy2);        

       }


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String axis = null;
    // add into array current drawn pattern
for (int i=0; i<(panel1.linex1.size()); ++i ){
drawnpattern.add((int)panel1.linex1.get(i));
    drawnpattern.add((int)panel1.liney1.get(i));
    drawnpattern.add((int)panel1.linex2.get(i));
    drawnpattern.add((int)panel1.liney2.get(i));
    // append current drawn pattern line data
    axis = ("Line "+i+": "+" x1: "+panel1.linex1.get(i)+" y1: "+panel1.liney1.get(i)+" x2: "+panel1.linex2.get(i)+" y2: "+panel1.liney2.get(i)+".");
jta.append(axis);
    jta.append("\n");
    // read file and append file data to filepattern array
    filepattern.add(26);
    filepattern.add(50);
    filepattern.add(36);
    filepattern.add(130);
    filepattern.add(36);
    filepattern.add(130);
    filepattern.add(64);
    filepattern.add(97);
    filepattern.add(64);
    filepattern.add(97);
    filepattern.add(81);
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(81);    
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(100);
    filepattern.add(96);
    filepattern.add(100);
    filepattern.add(96);
    filepattern.add(122);
    filepattern.add(128);
    filepattern.add(122);
    filepattern.add(128);
    filepattern.add(127);
    filepattern.add(57);
    // after adding original data then we need to calculate the values of original data and also the incoming data.
    // then we need to use our formula to compare

}                                        
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btn;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtondraw;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jta;
private my.jpanel.Panel panel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Try `revalidate()` instead of `repaint()`.

Comment: nope nothing happens!